# Is it possible to use Drupal Commerce along with Ubercart in the same project?

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart, drupal-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce site for a Travel agency. There are 4-5 features like hotel,tour etc. I have already finished my development for its tour section. The tour pricing is developed using Ubercart module. But due to some restricted features of Ubercart, i want to use Drupal commerce for hotel pricing. Now I want to know if it is possible to use Ubercart for Tour Section and Drupal commerce for Hotel Section in this project?

Comment: did you use both modules at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to use Drupal commerce and Ubercart together. Finalize one and extend it as per requirement.

Also check this out : https://drupalcommerce.org/

Cheers!!!